# pop-up modal div

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there ready code snippet for using pop-up modal div without using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LivePipe Modal uses Prototype.

http://livepipe.net/control/window

Answer (score 4):

Truly, I am not trying to be a jerk, but it seems like a simple Google search for `modal div` turns up literally tens of results with tutorials, downloadable code, etc.